# Can anybody identify these Marvel characters?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, video-games

I think they are mostly Marvel characters, but I don't know. Could anybody please name them?

A: [image]

B: [image: ![enter image description here]

C: [image]

D: [image]

E: [image]

F: [image]

G: [image]

H: [image]

I: [image]

J: [image]

K: [image]

L: [image]

M: [image]

N: [image]

O: [image]

P: [image]

Q: [image]

R: [image]

S: [image]

Comment: Why do you think they are all Marvel characters? Where did they come from?

Comment: Most of them look like sprites from the game *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A: [image]

Looks like the [Brood](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/) sprite from *[X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse](https://capcom.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_Mutant_Apocalypse)*.

> B: [image]

Looks like the [Evil Sasquatch](https://www.giantbomb.com/evil-sasquatch/3005-19305/) sprite from *[Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems](https://capcom.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_In_War_of_the_Gems)*. (I believe the 'evil' versions of characters in this game were inspired by the *[Infinity War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_War)* storyline in the comics, which featured evil doppelgangers of numerous Marvel heroes.)

> C: [image]

Judging by the stance and other visual details, I'm guessing this is some sort of variation/edit of the [Gambit](https://www.gamemite.com/img/game/211029213520.jpg) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*. Not sure if it's official or fan-made, or if it's meant to resemble another existing character.

> D: [image]

Looks like the [Iron Man](https://www.mobygames.com/game/snes/marvel-super-heroes-in-war-of-the-gems/screenshots/gameShotId,222442/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*, although the colours don't match. Possibly a [palette swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_swap) or fan-edit.

> E: [image]

Looks like the [Evil Puck](https://www.giantbomb.com/evil-puck/3005-19306/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> F: [image]

Looks like the [Guard Robot](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> G: [image]

Looks like the [Apocalypse](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/53fcd5b1e4b0826cfdf767e2/1416526289950-XFSTAFP7KF5392H84ZSQ/Wolverine+vs+Apocalypse?format=1500w) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> H: [image]

Looks like the [Tusk](https://www.giantbomb.com/tusk/3005-19216/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> I: [image]

Looks like the [Evil Vision](https://www.giantbomb.com/evil-vision/3005-19312/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> J: [image]

Looks like the [Magus](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> K: [image]

Judging by the stance and other visual details, I'm guessing this is some sort of variation/edit of the [Cyclops](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*. Not sure if it's official or fan-made, or if it's meant to resemble another existing character. Reminds me a little of the DC Comics villain, [Owlman](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Thomas_Wayne,_Jr._(Earth_3)), but I doubt it's him.

> L: [image]

Looks like the [Exodus](https://www.mobygames.com/game/snes/x-men-mutant-apocalypse/screenshots/gameShotId,199618/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> M: [image]

Looks like the [Nebula](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> N: [image]

Looks like the [Chrome](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> O: [image]

Looks like the [Blackheart](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/) sprite from the *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> P: [image]

Looks like the [Evil Daredevil](https://www.giantbomb.com/evil-daredevil/3005-19307/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

> Q: [image]

???

> R: [image]

Looks like the [Omega Red](https://www.mobygames.com/game/snes/x-men-mutant-apocalypse/screenshots/gameShotId,199615/) sprite from *X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse*.

> S: [image]

Looks like the [Doombot](https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/) sprite from *Marvel Super Heroes in War of the Gems*.

Comment: The Q looks either like a resprite of something, or something entirely fan-made based off of something like Gundam. It looks like that, whatever it is, it has a squarish helmet that can pop up like a motorcycle helmet, which reveals a small head with a blinking visor. I've never seen anything like that before, but it's certainly not from Marvel.

Comment: K looks like it could be the villain Annihilus.

Comment: thank you. I knew it was sprites from a game but I didnt know which one and now I got most names thanks to you and that site.

Comment: Chances are that C and K are likely to be fan-made indeed; more so than D which I also believe to be fan-made. Notice how flat the colours look like sometimes? Especially the head of C. Compare it to the relief of the rest of the body.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know where these images are from.

Q, for example, looks more like an Autobot than a Marvel character.

G = Apocalypse (X-Men Villian) [image: Apocalypse]

R = Omega Red (X-Men Villian)[image]

Answer (score 0):

A: A [Brood](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brood_(Race)).

B: [Sasquatch](https://www.writeups.org/sasquatch-alpha-flight-marvel-comics/) of Alpha Flight.

E: The costume is clearly [Puck](https://www.writeups.org/puck-alpha-flight-marvel-comics-judd/) of Alpha Flight, and he was apparently [turned into a green Hulk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Judd_(Earth-TRN841)) at one point, so that is my best guess.

G: [Apocalypse](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Apocalypse_(Marvel))

I doubt they are all Marvel characters, or I believe I would have recognized more.

Comment: The Spriter's Resource is always a good place to check for video game sprites. On the [X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse][1] page you can see that G is Apocalypse, A is Brood, N is Chrome, L is Exodus, R is Omega Red and H is Tusk.
Then, looking at the [Marvel Super Heroes: War of the Gems][3] page we find O is Black Heart, S is Doombot, P is Daredevil, E is Puck, B is Sasquatch, M is Nebula, I is Vision and J is Magus.

  [1]: https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/
  [3]: https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/marvelherogems/

Comment: @Showsni D looks like a resprite of Iron Man from War of the Gems. It looks identical in every way, save for the colours and the beam. F is also a robot you fight in X-Men: Mutant Apocalypse, although I don't remember seeing a name.

Comment: F is "Guard Robot": https://www.spriters-resource.com/snes/xmenapoc/sheet/21649/